# How to delete row from the database with smallest id?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

everyone! I need some help. So my problem = title. How can I delete a row in the database with the smallest(lowest) id? I mean the following:

Database structure:

```
id   title  desc
21   One    desc1
22   Two    desc2
23   Three  desc3
```

And I need to delete the row with id 21. This id will be dynamic always.

UPD: here are my tries:

```
$delete_row_query = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM `$grapht` WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM `$grapht` ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)");

    if(statement) {
        mysqli_query($conn, $delete_row_query);
        echo "CLEANED";
    }
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: `if(statement)` - Um... what's this? Looks like pseudo code. If not, then `statement` is treated as a constant.

Comment: You're also querying twice, to which that should be throwing you a notice/warning about.

Comment: Everyone so far missed something here. Look at their PHP again.

Comment: Please be careful when posting questions without all relevant code from the start. This caused some issues here, since your php failed you as I originally stated in comments here. The answers given are correct as per your original post  https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44588212/1 and you need to correct that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your sql query to

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

**Edit:**

It must be noted that this answer was based on the original post before adding their PHP after.

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44588212/1

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM table);
```

This will delete the entry with the lowest current ID in the table.

**Edit:**

It must be noted that this answer was based on the original post before adding their PHP after.

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44588212/1

**Edit 2:**

Addressing your bigger problem here:

```
$delete_row_query = "DELETE FROM `$grapht` WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM `$grapht` ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)"

if(statement) {
    mysqli_query($conn, $delete_row_query);
    echo "CLEANED";
}
```

you were trying to query the result of the first query without a statement.
Which is why you got your empty query error.

I've fixed it above, and it should now work fine.

Comment: It says: Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in

Comment: Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function at least on MySQL 5.7

Comment: @RiggsFolly fixed it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly He even showed in clear light here what the error is, given the OP's php. `Error Code: 1111`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for mentioning that it was answered before the PHP was posted, and I've since edited the answer to address the PHP problem as well.

Comment: @FMashiro you're welcome. Yeah, that question/OP caused some friction and I placed [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588212/how-to-delete-row-from-the-database-with-smallest-id/44588234#comment76168876_44588212) about it. I needed to set the record straight for everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `limit` and `order by` in `delete`:

```
delete t
    from t
    order by id
    limit 1;
```

**Edit:**

It must be noted that this answer was based on the original post before adding their PHP after.

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44588212/1

Comment: Given your rep Gordon, I feel you missed something or didn't mention it intentionally. You should see their php again and as per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588212/how-to-delete-row-from-the-database-with-smallest-id#comment76164170_44588212) I left under the question, and another above it.

Comment: And what is the reason for all the downvotes on the answers.  This (and others) answer the question correctly -- especially as originally asked before the edits.

Comment: Again Gordon. Given your rep... I feel I don't have to elaborate on that. I can justify the downvotes. I find it rather odd that you now surface after the downvote but not from my original comment from well over a half hour ago.

Comment: I think what fred is saying here is that while this provides a query that would work in the OP's first call to `mysqli_query()` the if statement and then the second attempt at a a call to `mysqli_query()` make absolutely no sense and should really have been mentioned/corrected in everybodies answers if they were trying to give a full and comprehensive answer to the question

Comment: @ GordonLinoff In all fairness here (to the OP and others), what you should have included in your answer or placed as a comment under your answer, would have been that you were specifically answering the "mysql" and not the "php". What @RiggsFolly wrote in a comment above, explains it well.  Note I wasn't trying to be malicious in any way and felt that my downvote(s) were justified. I don't want any bad blood, I voiced my opinion about it. I also feel that you should have responded to my first comment and to at least tell me that that was all you were answering to.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok I see the revisions now and I hope you will accept my sincere apology for someone else's error. I edited your answer and gave you an upvote for it. Edit: I also edited everyone else's answer and removed my downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM table ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1
```